# How do you align tick labels in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to build an infographic using matplotlib, and I want to left-align all the y-axis' tick labels.

[image]

I want to move all the tick labels to the left — I want them all to begin from the same x-location as `District of Columbia`.

I tried to do that using [`Axes.set_yticklabels`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yticklabels.html), but I can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 4):

Did you try using the `set_horizontalalignment()` for each tick on the axis?

```
for tick in ax.yaxis.get_majorticklabels():
    tick.set_horizontalalignment("left")
```

Comment: Thanks, this one works, but the labels now overlap with the lines — it's probably best to use `ax.text()` for more flexibility (like @Arne indicated earlier).  Image: https://i.imgur.com/BJXAHKc.png

Answer (score 2):

A flexible approach is to plot the labels separately, with `ax.text()`. Here is a simple example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = [0, 1, 2]
width = [2, 2, 3]
labels = ['Colorado', 'Massachusetts', 'DC']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.barh(y=y, width=width)
ax.set_yticks(y)
ax.set_yticklabels([]) 

for i, yi in enumerate(y):
    ax.text(-0.8, yi, labels[i], horizontalalignment='left', verticalalignment='center')
```

[image: label alignment example]

Just adjust the offset (`-0.8` in the example above) according to your longest label.

Answer (score 0):

Pick a padding that's right for your list of labels

```
ax.tick_params(pad=25)    
ax.set_yticklabels(labels, ha='left')
```