# How to align y-axis tick labels left justified in matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib

How to align y-axis tick labels left justified in matplotlib?

The 1st answer below gives renderer error at this line:
**[Matplotlib: Aligning y-ticks to the left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15882249/matplotlib-aligning-y-ticks-to-the-left)**

```
pad = max(T.label.get_window_extent().width for T in yax.majorTicks)
```

The 2nd answer below uses **text** which is input dependent, for each list of yticklabels you have to first find the best x position and then you can use. Therefore, it not a solution for automated code.

**[How do you align tick labels in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62813090/how-do-you-align-tick-labels-in-matplotlib)**

Here is the code to replicate the problem:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)

ax.plot([0,.25,.5, 1], [0,1,2,3])
ticklabels = ax.get_xticklabels()
ax.set_yticks([0, 1, 2, 3])
yticklabels = []
for i in ['xxxxxxxx', 'yyy', 'zzzzzzzzzzzzz', 'ttttt']:
    yticklabels.append(f"{i:<15}")

print(yticklabels)
ax.set_yticklabels(yticklabels )
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Depending on your backend, for the first solution you might need to call `fig.canvas.draw()` instead of `plt.draw()`.  (Or `plt.pause(0.1)`.)

Comment: I didn't set any backend.

Comment: You also have a backend. If you don't set it, you get the default one depending on the environment where you are running your code. `import matplotlib; print(matplotlib.get_backend())` to see the one you're currently using

Comment: My backend is MacOSX. How to left align the y axis ticklabels? why is this this much difficult?

Comment: Did you try to replace `plt.draw()` with `fig.canvas.draw()`? Did you get an error?  And with `plt.draw()` followed by `plt.pause(0.1)`? It's not that hard to test and [complete](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68234707/edit) your question with all relevant information.  You might want to reread [How to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Things are a bit complicated, because exact measures can only be gotten when the plot is really drawn; changing parameters changes the plot and the measurements; for speed, matplotlib tries only to render when explicitly needed.

Comment: If you want spaces and all characters to have the same width, you can use `ax.set_yticklabels(yticklabels, family='consolas')`. This changes the font to a monospaced one, which usually doesn't look as nice as the standard fonts.

Comment: @JohanC  fig.canvas.draw() didn't change anything.  plt.draw() followed by plt.pause(0.1) just shows numbers at the y axis tick labels instead of given text. For your second recommendation, font and how it looks matter in a figure, that's why I'm trying to left justify. Thanks but I couldn't solve this issue yet.

Comment: If you only see numbers, that means you forgot to call `ax.set_yticklabels(yticklabels)`? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68234707/edit) your question and add all relevant information, especially the exact code you tried last.

Comment: Left justifying a piece of text based on the width of another piece of text is indeed hard.  Yaxis ticks are right-justified for a reason. If you want them left justified, you will have to jump through hoops.

Comment: @JodyKlymak I see.